# Can Scrivener 2 import a TeX file?

Tags: latex

I've found the way to [publish a TeX document](http://timbrandes.com/blog/2012/02/28/howto-write-your-thesis-in-latex-using-scrivener-2-multimarkdown-3-and-bibdesk/) with Scrivener 2.

Now I'm curious that whether Scrivener 2 has a capability of importing a LaTeX file and establishing a ***Scrivener style*** document structure or not.

I'm asking it because I'm writing a paper with other people who are not using Scrivener.

Comment: I would be surprised if it could but why don't you hop over to http://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php to download the free trial and try yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Scrivener 2 does import LaTeX files as RTF (see dialog box below).

[image]

I imported a sample LaTeX file into a Scrivener project, and the result was test-latex.scriv. See below.

[image]